# Python Selenium: Keep on getting Connection Refused Error on DigitalOcean VPS

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

The VPS runs Ubuntu. I have tried using HTMLUNITDRIVER, geckdriver, chromedriver. It still will not work.

Here is the error:[Error](https://hastebin.com/ekixaxiruv.sql)

Here is the start of the code: [Code](https://hastebin.com/wahoridipa.hs)

Comment: Please do not use screenshot for error/code, please copy them within your post

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include